Copy files from Folder A to folder B on windows server through azure DevOps pipeline
I need to take a backup of a files from folder A to folder B in windows server using azure devops pipeline running microsoft hosted widnows agent. i have given ssh coonection details in azure DevOps connection, i tried below two tasks but either of them is not working
try -1
- task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
  inputs:
    sshEndpoint: 'MyserviceSSH'  # Name of your SSH service connection
    sourceFolder: 'C:\Users\folder a'  # Folder to back up
    contents: '**'  # All files inside the source folder
    targetFolder: 'C:\Users\folderb'  # Backup folder on the same Windows server
    cleanTargetFolder: false  # Do not clean the backup folder before copying
    overwrite: true  # Overwrite files if they already exist
    isWindowsOnTarget: true
    displayName: 'Backup Target Files to Serv'

I'm getting error as sourcefolder dosent exit though its is connected to windows server through ssh and source folder is present on remote windows server
try-2
- task: SSH@0
  inputs:
    sshEndpoint: 'MyserviceSSH'
    runOptions: 'commands'
    commands: |
      powershell -Command "& {
          $SourceFolder = 'C:\\Users\\harsha\\foldera;
          $BackupFolder = 'C:\\Users\\harsha\\folderb';

          # Create the backup folder if it doesn't exist
          if (!(Test-Path -Path $BackupFolder)) {
              New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $BackupFolder -Force;
          }

          # Copy files from source to backup folder
          Copy-Item -Path \"$SourceFolder\\*\" -Destination $BackupFolder -Recurse -Force;
      }"

I'm getting error as ##[error]  'tr' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. ##[error]Command failed with errors on remote machine
could you please help me on this on how can we copy files from one folder to another through azuredevops pipeline on windows server.if there are anyway for it.

If you plan to do this regularly, you can create an environment in Azure DevOps and add your Windows Server as a virtual machine resource. Then, use the CopyFiles@2 task to copy the files. This is an alternative approach that doesn’t require SSH.

we do this on monthly basis, so i would need to copy files  via ssh tasks, please let me know if anything would need to modify with the provided tasks
